# Use a regex to extract many different strings within a file

Tags: node.js, regex

The code below is an example of what a typical file would look like.

```
<actions>
   <input value="this is string 1" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="[tab]" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="this is string 2" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="[tab]" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
</actions>
```

I would like to use a regular expression to select multiple strings within a file, then extract those strings and save them to a new file. I need to only select the strings that are inside of the " " after the value element. Then replace the [tab] with a new line.

At the end, I will need to concatenate the strings and new lines. Then save them as a new file. Using Node js.

Here is the regular expression I am already using: /value=(.*)/. This expression can select the stings but also selects other elements as well.

What is the best way to modify (or replace) my existing expression to accomplish what im seeking?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally better to use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) rather than regex to parse XML type objects. Here's an example of how one could work for your sample data:

```js
const data = `<actions>
   <input value="this is string 1" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="[tab]" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="this is string 2" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
   <input value="[tab]" movecursor="" xlatehostkeys="" encrypted="" />
</actions>`

const parser = new DOMParser();
const d = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
let result = '';
for (el of d.firstChild.childNodes) {
  if (el.nodeType == 1) result += el.getAttribute('value').replace(/^\[tab\]$/, '\n');
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for! As a follow up question, There are over 300+ files, is there a way to accomplish the same result, without modifying the data inside each file?

Comment: @Jordan this doesn't modify the data inside the file. If you put the parsing and processing inside code which loops over the files, you should be able to generate a result strng which is the sum of processing all the files e.g. something like `result = ''; for (f in files) { parseFromString(filecontents); process as per above answer; }`

Comment: Im getting a type error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes'). What am i missing?

Comment: That would seem to suggest one of the xml files doesn't have more than one node in the xml (or perhaps it doesn't contain valid xml, hard to be sure without seeing the exact error). Can you check the xml that is being parsed?